# UWP MapControl Tap/Click events not firing

Tags: uwp

I can't get the UWP MapControl to fire events such as Tapped or DoubleTapped MapElementClick ETC.GotFocus is firing ok.

```
        <maps:MapControl
            Name="myFirstMap"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="10"
            DoubleTapped="myFirstMap_DoubleTapped"
            IsDoubleTapEnabled="True"
            IsTapEnabled="True"
            MapElementClick="MyFirstMap_MapElementClick"
            MapServiceToken="myKey"
            Tapped="myFirstMap_Tapped" />


    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I must be doing something daft any ideas? Event handled in code behind.

```
private void myFirstMap_DoubleTapped(object sender, doubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //nothing happening here?!
}
```

Tried attaching GotFocus and that is firing. Seems very odd.
It's all working except for the events. .

Comment: "ubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e". Is that a typo in your question or a typo in your code?

Comment: Typo sorry about that!

Comment: Can you post your full XAML - Something else is probably stopping it from firing as the above code works fine for me, without the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another two hours of my life I will never get back!
Do not use:

```
   Tapped="EventHandler"
```

But

```
 MapTapped="EventHandler"
```

There is a difference between the events Tapped and DoubleTapped and MapTapped and MapDoubleTapped.

Comment: Yes, but you mentioned that MapElementClick wasn't firing either?

Comment: According to MSDN - MapElementClick occurs when the user taps the MapControl or clicks on it with the left mouse button. I believe your MapTapped event will override this as MapTapped also handles mouse clicks.

Comment: Which also explains why my test worked as I tested the MapElementClick event on my non-touch PC rather than the non-working tap events. Problem solved :)

Comment: Hi @PaulStanley if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.